# Can we release an update of an iOS app only to some users?

Tags: ios

We have an iOS app available on the App Store.

We want to release an update of the app but we want the release to happen in a phase wise manner i.e. the updated app should be available to only 10% of the users initially. After some time, say 1 week, it should get available to 20% more users and so on.

I was told this is possible on Android.
Can it be done for iOS apps as well? I tried to search (including this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html) as well) but could not get concrete answers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nah! Not on the App Store. There's a feature in TestFlight to make a version available for selected users but that is meant for beta testing of the app.

Answer (score 3):

Currently this is possible for both iOS and Android

[Apple phased release](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev3d65fcee1)

If you choose this option, your version update will be released over a 7-day period to a percentage of your users (selected at random by their Apple ID) on iOS with automatic updates turned on. Users are not notified that that they are in a phased release of your app.

[image: Phased release]

[Android staged rollouts](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6346149?hl=en)

You can release an app update to production using a staged rollout. With a staged rollout, your update reaches only a percentage of your users, which you can increase over time.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, we cannot do this in AppStore. If you want to do A/B testing(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing), then there are several tools in market to assist you with that. If you want to do beta testing, then `TestFlight` is the one to go for.

https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/videos#testflight-beta-testing

Answer (score 1):

You can use TestFlight where you send you test subjects the app to their email, and then they open your app with the apple TestFlight app. The limit is 2,000 people I think.

Answer (score 0):

For (beta) testing there are different options. You could create specific groups within TestFlight and rollout to them or share your app over DIAWI with the people you want to reach. For production - let's say AppStore - it's not possible to do a partial rollout or update cycle.